# XPath query with Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the text from the `<reps>` element for this website using Google Sheets:

**https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/TCC/2018/1602.html**

I'm using this formula in a cell:

```
=importxml("https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/TCC/2018/1602.html",/html/body/center[2]/p[4]/b/reps)
```

What I want it to import is this text:

> Miss Chantal-Aimee Doerries QC and Mr Marc Lixenberg (instructed by Morgan LaRoche) for the Claimants
>   Mr Adrian Williamson QC and Mr Thomas Lazur (instructed by Glovers Solicitors LLP) for the Defendant

Any idea why my formula isn't working? I got the XPath using 'Copy Xpath' in the console.

Would massively appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/TCC/2018/1602.html";"//*");112;1)
```

[image: 6]